# "The image cannot be displayed error" when sending image over socket in C++

Tags: c++, image, sockets

I am trying to send files of all types over a socket to the browser in C++. I am able to send .`txt` and `.html` files over the socket fine, but when I try to send a jpeg, I get the error `The image "localhost:8199/img.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors`. I am not sure why my program works fine for sending text files but cannot handle images. This is how I read the file and write it to the client:

```
 int fileLength = read(in, buf, BUFSIZE);
    buf[fileLength] = 0;
    char *fileContents = buf;

    while (fileLength > 0) {

        string msg =  "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:" + fileExt + "\r\n\r\n\r\nHere is response data";
        int bytes_written;

        if(vrsn == "1.1" || vrsn == "1.0"){
            write(fd, msg.c_str(), strlen(msg.c_str()));    
            bytes_written = write(fd, fileContents, fileLength);
        } else {
            bytes_written = write(fd, fileContents, fileLength);
        }

        fileLength -= bytes_written;
        fileContents += bytes_written;  
    }
```

Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/vU9N0gRi

If I check the response headers in my browser network console, I see that the `Content-Type` is `image/jpeg` so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Are image files handled differently than normal text files? If so, what exactly do I have to do in order to handle sending image files to the browser?

Comment: corrupted header and bad length (images are not strings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> string msg =  "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:" + fileExt + "\r\n\r\n\r\nHere is response data";

This is an invalid HTTP response for binary data, like images.  After the terminating `\r\n\r\n` at the end of the HTTP headers, **everything after that is message body data**.  So, you are sending `\r\nHere is response data` as the first few bytes of your images, corrupting them.  You need to remove that altogether, even for your `txt` and `html` files.

Worse, you are sending `msg` on **every loop iteration**, so you are preceding every buffer of file data with your HTTP response string, thoroughly corrupting your image data further.

Also, your response is missing `Content-Length` and `Connection: close` response headers.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int sendRaw(int fd, const void *buf, int buflen)
{
    const char *pbuf = static_cast<const char*>(buf);
    int bytes_written;

    while (buflen > 0) {
        bytes_written = write(fd, pbuf, buflen);
        if (written == -1) return -1;
        pbuf += bytes_written;  
        buflen -= bytes_written;
    }

    return 0;
}

int sendStr(int fd, const string &s)
{
    return sendRaw(fd, s.c_str(), s.length());
}

...

struct stat s;
fstat(in, &s);
off_t fileLength = s.st_size;

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bytes_read, bytes_written;

if ((vrsn == "1.1") || (vrsn == "1.0")) {
    ostringstream msg;
    msg << "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        << "Content-Type:" << fileExt << "\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << fileLength << "\r\n"
        << "Connection: close\r\n"
        << "\r\n";
    sendStr(fd, msg.str());
}

while (fileLength > 0) {
    bytes_read = read(in, buf, min(fileLength, BUFSIZE));
    if (bytes_read <= 0) break;
    if (sendRaw(fd, buf, bytes_read) == -1) break;
    fileLength -= bytes_read;  
}

close(fd);
```

Answer (score 2):

`write(fd, msg.c_str(), strlen(msg.c_str()));` - have you considered that an image may contain null (zero) bytes? so treating it as a C style string is not really a good idea.

You should be sending your raw data and writing the size of that data - which is *not* just up until the first null byte.

Comment: Is the raw data not being sent by this line here:  `bytes_written = write(fd, fileContents, fileLength);` ?

Comment: `vrsn` is a string. It's the 1.1 portion of the HTTP/1.1 string.

Comment: @MahmudAdam: you are sending the HTTP response all wrong.  See my answer.